# Don't use gp register

Tags: mips, mips32

```
jmp_gen_exp:
    la      k0, gen_exp_handler         # requires jump indirect
    jr      k0
    nop
```

the compiler generate the above code to

```
000019bc:    8f9affc8   lw  $26,-56($28) //lw k0,-56(gp)        
000019c0:    00000000   nop             
000019c4:    275a17d8   addiu   $26,$26,6104=0x17d8   //addiu k0,k0,6104    
000019c8:    03400008   jr  $26     //jr k0
```

How can I avoid the gp register use?

Comment: Your question is too wide. One option for you would be to compile the code with -static option. However, you'd better explain what exactly you are trying to achieve with this "don't use gp register" task.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the exact address of `gen_exp_handler` you can use `li` pseudoinstruction to load that address in register `$26`.
E.g. suppose `gen_exp_handler` address is `0x12345600` then you could issue

```
  li $k0, 0x12345600
```